# how to escape new line while parsing json from xml

Tags: java, xml, json

I am learning to parse json from xml, and i parsed it but when i parsed json from xml, I am getting new line character in my json can anyone please suggest how can i remove it, Here is my java code.
    public class Test2 {

```
private URL url = null;
    private InputStream inputStream = null;
    private int test = 4;

    public void getXMLfromJson() {
        try {
            url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sample.xml");
            inputStream = url.openStream();
            String xml = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
            org.json.JSONObject JSON = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
            String json = JSON.toString(test);
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                url = null;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test2().getXMLfromJson();
    }
}
```

Xml file from which i am reading is as follows,

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk01">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
          with XML.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk02">
          <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
          <title>Midnight Rain</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
          <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
          an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
          of the world.</description>
       </book>
    </catalog>
```

Here is the out put of my program in which i am having escape character and space where new line is encountered

```
    {"catalog": {"book": [
    {
        "genre": "Computer",
        "id": "bk01",
        "author": "Gambardella, Matthew",
        "title": "XML Developer's Guide",
        "price": 44.95,
        "publish_date": "2000-10-01",
        "description": "An in-depth look at creating applications\n      with XML."
    },
    {
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "id": "bk02",
        "author": "Ralls, Kim",
        "title": "Midnight Rain",
        "price": 5.95,
        "publish_date": "2000-12-16",
        "description": "A former architect battles corporate zombies,\n      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen\n      of the world."
    }
]}}
```

How can i escape this \n new line character and space.

Comment: What do you mean by "escape"? Given the original source the JSON output is pitch perfect -- it includes text as it was in the XML. Including newlines and spaces!

Comment: i dont want to include newlines and spaces

Comment: Let me know that third party library of `XML` and `IOUtils` classes. Lets see if there are some methods in the these APIs allowing what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should find a way so that your XML doesn't have them. What you are doing above is just conversion and not transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing my solution. Simply just replace the line break in XML before converting it into JSON.

```
//to replace line break in XML
public string escapeLineBreak(string myXml) {
   if (myXml != null && myXml != "") {
        return myXml.Replace("\r\n", "\\n");
   } else {
        return myXml;
   }
}
```